# React on screen doesn't work when I use it with React full-screen component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullpage.js

When I scroll down within the full page react's slides, though the page on the viewport of the screen the background color of the div does not change, I use react-on-screen npm package withing the full page react component but when I use the react-on-screen without full page react component it works great, I think when I scrolldown within the full-page-react slides the viewport don't think the new slides are new pages so the div background color doesn't change. Plus I tried to resize the window when the div in the last page is on the screen then the background is changed. Can you help me about this problem?

```
render() {
    const { height } = this.state;
    return (
      <Layout>
        <ReactFullpage
          refresh
          keyboardScrolling
          lazyLoading
          scrollOverflowReset={false}
          slidesNavigation={deger}
          onLeave={this.onLeave}
          render={({ state, fullpageApi }) => {
            return (
              <ReactFullpage.Wrapper>
                <React.Fragment>
                  <div className="section">
                    <p>Section 1</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="section">
                    <div className="Index_LogoWrapper" style={{ height }}>
                      <LogoImage />
                      <div className="Index_ContactUsWrapper">
                        <div className="Index_ContactUs">
                For more information contact us at&nbsp;
                          <a href="mailto:info@mail.io">info@mail.io</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="section">
                    <TrackVisibility>
                      <ComponentToTrack />
                    </TrackVisibility>
                  </div>
                </React.Fragment>
              </ReactFullpage.Wrapper>
            );
          }}
        />
      </Layout>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the component you use to change the color relies on the scrolling position then you'll have to use the option `scrollBar` of fullPage.js in your react-fullpage component.

Otherwise I would encourage you to use the fullpage.js callbacks such as `afterLoad` or `onLeave` or even use the fullpage.js state classes that get added to the body element.

See one of my video tutorials about how to perform CSS 3 animations with fullpage.js state classes:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M